# sending snapshot time from physical process to node in Castalia

Tags: omnet++

When the physical process replies to node through sensor manager, I want to send `source_snapshot[i].time` along with `retVal`.

For this purpose, I am using `phyMsg->setTimestamp()` function in Physical Process and `getTimestamp()` wherever needed.

Is this the correct practice?

EDIT: or maybe I can add a time variable in physical process  message structure?

Comment: Why do you need this value? Do you understand what this value is?

Comment: Different instances of physical process are defined by snapshots and a snapshot is a tuple (value,time,x,y). 
when a certain snapshot is considered according to stime of node, the time of snapshot is also important along with return value in my application scenario hence i need to transmit it to the application.

Comment: Important for what? All the node ever cares is the value returned from the physical process at a specific time and a specific location. It does not care how the phy process computed this value.

Comment: The node does not know there are snapshots, sources, or anything like that. The node just wants a value when it's taking a sample with its sensing device. The phy process module **models** the underlying physical process that provides this value.

Comment: I am working on target tracking application and retracing the path at sink node. To retrace the path, i need the time of corresponding snapshot to be forwarded to application module along with retVal, in response to requestSensorReading function.

Comment: No the nodes do not need to know the true path of the target. This defeats the whole purpose of building a target tracking system. I suggest you consult with your advisor about this.